# How can I reduce this repetition

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have this CSS but as you can see I am repeating the same thing for different categories...how can I reduce this code?

```
.dropdown .cars-category{
   float: left;
   margin-left: 1%;

}


.dropdown .trucks-category{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 1%;
}


.dropdown .trucks-category > li > a {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #546aa4;
}

.dropdown .trucks-category > li.last > a {
    border-bottom-width: 0;
}

.dropdown .trucks-category > li > a:hover,
.dropdown .trucks-category > li > a:focus,

.dropdown .trucks-category > .active > a,
.dropdown .trucks-category > .active > a:hover,
.dropdown .trucks-category > .active > a:focus {
    color: #546aa4;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #e7eded;
    outline: 0;
}


.dropdown .cars-category > li > a {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #546aa4;
}

.dropdown .cars-category > li.last > a {
    border-bottom-width: 0;
}

.dropdown .cars-category > li > a:hover,
.dropdown .cars-category > li > a:focus,

.dropdown .cars-category > .active > a,
.dropdown .cars-category > .active > a:hover,
.dropdown .cars-category > .active > a:focus {
    color: #546aa4;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #e7eded;
    outline: 0;
}
```

Comment: Without the HTML structure this is pretty nebulous... But in general, when you are declaring the same property values in multiple rules, you can just concoct the rules together by adding the selectors all to one rule. Note that if you are properly compressing the file as its sent to the user, this repetition will be mostly taken care of as far as transmission size of the file.

Comment: You could all take a look [Less](http://lesscss.org/) or [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/)

Comment: You have a couple of rule contents which are repeated (e.g., `.cars-category > .active` and `.trucks-category > .active`. So you could combine them. Also, you might be able to get rid of the `.dropdown` specifier since the rest is already quite specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Opt 1 - Change HTML and then Reduce

Using two classes instead of a hyphenated class is going to reduce it the most. So instead of `class="trucks-category"` in the html, use `class="trucks category" and`class="cars category". Also, some of your last block is unnecessary (assuming the `.active` is on an `li` element). Reduces to 7 selectors:

```
.dropdown .cars.category { /*could eliminate .category if no other .cars under */ 
   float: left;            /*the .dropdown menu, see .trucks for example */
   margin-left: 1%;
}


.dropdown .trucks { /*removed category if not needed to differentiate */
    float: right;
    margin-right: 1%;
}


.dropdown .category > li > a {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #546aa4;
}

.dropdown .category > li.last > a {
    border-bottom-width: 0;
}

.dropdown .category > .active > a,
.dropdown .category > li > a:hover, 
.dropdown .category > li > a:focus
/* .dropdown .category > .active > a:hover, UNNEEDED */
/* .dropdown .category > .active > a:focus UNNEEDED */ {
    color: #546aa4;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #e7eded;
    outline: 0;
}
```

### Opt 2 - Target the Same Value on the Class Name

Like Option 1, but keeping your hyphenated classes. This is only useful if you do not have other `-category` classes that are *different css* and under `.dropdown`. If not, then this works:

```
.dropdown .cars-category { 
   float: left;            
   margin-left: 1%;
}


.dropdown .trucks-category {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 1%;
}


.dropdown [class*="-category"] > li > a {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #546aa4;
}

.dropdown [class*="-category"] > li.last > a {
    border-bottom-width: 0;
}

.dropdown [class*="-category"] > .active > a,
.dropdown [class*="-category"] > li > a:hover, 
.dropdown [class*="-category"] > li > a:focus {
    color: #546aa4;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #e7eded;
    outline: 0;
}
```

I put option 1 as 1 just because I feel having the separate class names is more intuitive and more flexible.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine these at least

```
.dropdown .trucks-category > li > a {...}
```

and

```
.dropdown .cars-category > li > a {...}
```

basically those and the hover/focus... and .last, the car and truck category looks the same to me so you can bundle those up

```
.dropdown .trucks-category > li > a,
.dropdown .cars-category > li > a, {...}
```

Hope you know what I mean

Answer (score 2):

I would just add the categories to the selector.

```
.dropdown .trucks-category > li > a,
.dropdown .cars-category > li > a {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #546aa4;
}
```

You can also use the CSS3 attribute selectors to select based on if the class contains -category with [class*="-category"] which should work almost everywhere, but possibly be buggy on IE7-.

```
.dropdown [class*="-category"] > li > a{
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #546aa4;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a bit of grouping you could do

**CSS**

```
.dropdown .trucks-category > li > a,
.dropdown .cars-category > li > a {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #546aa4;
}

.dropdown .trucks-category > .active > a,
.dropdown .trucks-category > .active > a:hover,
.dropdown .trucks-category > .active > a:focus,
.dropdown .cars-category > li > a:hover,
.dropdown .cars-category > li > a:focus,
.dropdown .cars-category > .active > a,
.dropdown .cars-category > .active > a:hover,
.dropdown .cars-category > .active > a:focus {
    color: #546aa4;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #e7eded;
    outline: 0;
}

.dropdown .cars-category > li.last > a,
.dropdown .trucks-category > li.last > a {
    border-bottom-width: 0;
}
```